# c++: Can't insert a pair<int, MLine*> to an unordered_map

Tags: c++, pointers, unordered-map

I have my_map defined as:

```
 std::unordered_map<MyAction, MyLine * >;
```

(MyAction is an enum class)

where MyLine is `std::vector<MyPoint>`;

and MyLines is `std::vector<MyLine>`;

then with the following code:

```
for (const auto &myline : mylines) {

            my_map.insert(
                std::pair<MyAction, const Myline *>(MyAction::KEEP_1, &myline));
```

And I got the following errors:

```
my_utility.cpp:85:33: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
            my_map.insert(
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
my_project/external/clang/darwin/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:909:26: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'pair<my_namespace::MyAction, const Myline *>' to 'const pair<const std::__1::unordered_map<my_namespace::MyAction, std::__1::vector<math::Vector3<double>, std::__1::allocator<math::Vector3<double> > > *, std::__1::hash<my_namespace::MyAction>, std::__1::equal_to<my_namespace::MyAction>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const MyAction, std::__1::vector<math::Vector3<double>, std::__1::allocator<math::Vector3<double> > > *> > >::key_type, std::__1::unordered_map<my_namespace::MyAction, std::__1::vector<math::Vector3<double>, std::__1::allocator<math::Vector3<double> > > *, std::__1::hash<my_namespace::MyAction>, std::__1::equal_to<my_namespace::MyAction>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const MyAction, std::__1::vector<math::Vector3<double>, std::__1::allocator<math::Vector3<double> > > *> > >::mapped_type>' for 1st argument
    pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& __x)
                         ^
```

Any idea what was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you're casting away constness. the unordered map holds `MyLine*` but you're trying to insert a `const MyLine*`

Comment: How do I avoid that if I need to use const auto & in the for loop?

Comment: @Edamame: You can't.  You need to use `auto&` in the loop, or make new `MyLine` objects.  Or you could make the map hold `const MyLine *`

Answer (score 1):

Your map has `MyLine *` but in the insert function you also wrote `const`. Delete it and it should work.

Comment: If I removed the const in the insert, I got the error message saying clang/darwin/include/c++/v1/utility:422:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: 2nd argument ('const std::__1::vector<math::Vector3<double>, std::__1::allocator<math::Vector3<double> > > *') would lose const qualifier
    pair(_T1 const& __t1, _T2 const& __t2) .   -> I think this is because in the for loop I use const auto & , but I do need to do that

Comment: @Edamame If you have the object and you can't modify it, you should just make your unordered map hold `const MyLine*`.